# blank page in wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting the following error when I want to access the wp-admin sites of my wordpress installation:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare send_confirmation_on_profile_email() (previously declared in /wp-includes/user.php:2624) in /wp-admin/includes/ms.php on line 423
```

I looked around but couldn't find any help yet. Maybe someone of you knows how to fix this error.

Thanks.

Comment: theme and plugin folder send_confirmation_on_profile_email() function finded and replace name

Answer (score 0):

It seems `send_confirmation_on_profile_email()` function is used more than once. So what you need, is to find that function and rename it to its relevant name but make sure it does not match with the *send_confirmation_on_profile_email*